# Basic auth server response as unauthorized

Tags: android

I am new to android, i am using server call for signin with Basic Auth, its all works fine if i login with more than 45 letter in userid server response as Unauthorized. if user id is less than 45 letters its accepting 
my server call as follows

```
HttpURLConnection conn=null;
URL url = new URL(url string);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setReadTimeout(60000); 
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encode(Username+":"+Password));
conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
conn.connect();
```

Here conn.connect(); itself throws 401 : UnAuthorized

Comment: Try `String creds = String.format("%s:%s", "your_username", "your_password");
                String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);`

Comment: i tried it but not working same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   HttpURLConnection conn=null;
   URL url = new URL(url string);
   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
   conn.setDoOutput(true);
   conn.setDoInput(true);
   conn.setReadTimeout(60000); 
   String publicKey = "Username:Password";//getting your key
   String encodedString = Base64.encodeToString(publicKey.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
   String basicAuth = "Basic "+ encodedString; //space after Basic is matter.
   //setting header for authentication purpose, should use authorization as keyword it you change this it won't work anymore
   conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
   conn.connect();
```

Comment: try it with conn.setDoInput(true);

Comment: Thanks Nas, conn.setDoInput(true); is the fix

Comment: you are welcome. If it works then show your regards by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Code as below:

```
String credentials = String.format("%s:%s", "username", "password");  
String basicAuth = "Basic "+ Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
HttpURLConnection conn=null;
URL url = new URL(url string);
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setReadTimeout(60000); 
conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
conn.connect();
```